# How to see submitted manuscript status as co-author for the IEEE Access journal?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, open-access, ieee

The IEEE Access journal's submission has been changed to https://ieee.atyponrex.com. However, I cannot see the co-author's submitted manuscript in this new system. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not the corresponding author (the one who submitted the manuscript)? If so the easiest (perhaps only) way to see the submitted manuscript is to ask the corresponding author.